# Calling consumeAsync

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have implemented in-app purchases in my app but they are just being purchasable for one time in my onPurchaseFinished code where should I call the onConsumeListener?

```
@Override
public void onPurchasesUpdated(int responseCode, @Nullable List<Purchase> purchases) {


    if (responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponse.OK
            && purchases != null) {
       Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Purchased", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        adddata();


        for (Purchase purchase : purchases) {

        }
    } else if (responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponse.USER_CANCELED) {
        // Handle an error caused by a user cancelling the purchase flow.

    } else if (responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponse.ITEM_ALREADY_OWNED) {

        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Purchase Limit Reached! Try again later", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } else{

        // Handle any other error codes.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

could help someone, this for the Billing Library version 3:

```
ConsumeParams consumeParams = ConsumeParams
                .newBuilder()
                .setPurchaseToken(purchase.getPurchaseToken())
                .build();
        billingClient.consumeAsync(consumeParams, new ConsumeResponseListener() {
            @Override
            public void onConsumeResponse(BillingResult billingResult, String s) {

                //do something..
            }
        });
```

FYI , i am consuming the purchase after querying - **`queryPurchaseHistoryAsync`** , so my `purchase` object is of type: `PurchaseHistoryRecord`

Answer (score 0):

You can put

```
mHelper.consumeAsync(inventory.getPurchase(SKU_COINS),mConsumeFinishedListener);
```

as per your need.

As per my suggetion you can consume your product in **OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener** or **QueryInventoryFinishedListener**

Comment: Yes. Refer this link http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/implement-in-app-purchase-version-3